# Connection to a mysql database fails

Tags: mysql, .net

When I try and execute the following code to input  a value into a text box it comes up with an error saying : Authentication to host '' for user '' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user ''@'Adam-PC' (using password: NO)

Public Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Datetxt.TextChanged
        Dim ConnectionString As String
        Dim con As New MySqlConnection

```
    ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;database=river_data;allowuservariables=True"";Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"

    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    Dim query As String = "SELECT date FROM river-derwent-keswick-portinscale WHERE(`date` = '01.01.2013') "
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
    con.Open()

    Dim myreader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If myreader.Read() Then
        Datetxt.Text = myreader.GetValue(0)
    Else
        Me.Close()
        HomeForm.Show()
    End If
    myreader.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;database=river_data;allowuservariables=True"";Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
```

it looks like the user part is wrong.  Try:

```
ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user=root;database=river_data;allowuservariables=True"";Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
```

Comment: I changed the connection string and it still gives the error message stated above. @kaaheap